# change self keyword inside firefox content script sdk

Tags: firefox-addon

Inside the firefox sdk inside the content script the "self" variable is reserved for the object that you use to communicate with the addon-core.

Do any one happen to know if there is a way to use a different name for that object?

It interferes with JS code that uses window.self in order to check it's inside an iframe( window.top == window.self )

sadly this code can not be changed, I know there are other ways to create the same validation